# How do I find files/directories that are executable by anybody?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, permissions

I'm trying to find all files or directories that can be executed by EITHER user, group, or other. So far I have come up with this

```
find . -perm -u+x
```

I do not know how to search for group and other as well. I know that

```
find .-perm -ugo+x
```

will search for files/directories that can be executed by all 3 of those (essentially a+x).

I have searched and cannot figure out how to look for any of those 3. One place suggested

```
find . -perm -u+x, g+x, o+x
```

but i get the error

```
find: -perm: u+x,: illegal mode string
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :

```
find .  -perm /u=x,g=x,o=x
```

Comment: or shorter `find . -perm /111` (or older syntax `find . -perm +111`

Comment: Woops, forgot the `/` in my answer, +1. You should add an explanation of the error though.

Comment: when i try /111 or /u=x,g=x,o=x i still get "illegal mode string". however i tried +111 and that works. can somebody explain this to me, and is there an equivalent to +111 similar to /u=x,g=x, o=x?

Comment: @HaydenHolligan the `+111` is the (now) deprecated syntax (for the GNU find) and doing the same as `/111` - e.g. find any file with any exectutable bit. Yoou must have an terrible old linux or you have some BSD like system without the GNU find.

Comment: @HaydenHolligan Sounds like bsd find (e.g. osx). Worth noting that you should then use `+111` (executable for some user) and not `-111` (executable for all users).

Answer (score 1):

The POSIX-conformant syntax would be

```
find . \( -perm u=x -o -perm g=x -o -perm o=x \)
```

Each of the three `-perm` primaries checks if the file is executable by user, group, or other; they are joined by `-o` so that only one has to be true for the entire `\(...\)` group to be true.

Comment: +1. Don't think the parentheses are needed (they're really implied with the implied `-print`) unless you're specifying a specific action or other options.

Comment: Oh, good point. I'll leave them just in case some tries to add another filter to this answer.

Comment: I think you mean `-perm -u=x -o …` (note the dash before the `u`). Without dashes before u/g/o, the command will only find files with 0100 (---x------), 0010 (------x---), or 0001 (---------x) permissions *exactly* which might be what you want, but maybe not. (From the POSIX documentation: “If the <hyphen-minus> is omitted…evaluate as true when the file permission bits **exactly match** the value of the resulting template. Otherwise, if mode is prefixed by a <hyphen-minus>…evaluate as true if **at least** all the bits in the resulting template are set in the file permission bits.”)